# AWS Lambda python package and numpy

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I created a zip file having structure

```
-numpy
-pandas
...other dependecies
-src
   - lambda_handler
```

My lambda handler contains import numpy as np statement.

When trying to upload this to aws lambda zip and it gives error:-

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'src/sqs_trigger': Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
                 its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
                 your python interpreter from there.",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: The way you package the Lambda function is not ideal.  You should look into Lambda Layers: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/

Comment: Thanks @wkl! Using lambda layers solved this issue